# Display an image when Blob is returned from an API

Tags: vue.js, microsoft-graph-api, vuejs3, azure-ad-msal

I’m writing a Vue app which uses the Microsoft Graph API and SDK for initial authentication on the front end and then uses different aspects of the API throughout the app. Like displaying emails, OneDrive files, etc.

I’m using the profile photo from a users Microsoft account to display an avatar to other users. My issue is that when I call `{graphApi}/me/photo/$value` the result returned is a Blob. This is the endpoint provided in MS Graph.

I’ve read the MS Graph docs thoroughly, combed MDN & other sources and have not found a way to transform this result into a simple image in my markup.

Template markup:

```
<template>
  <img :src="userPhoto" :alt="user.displayName" />
</template>
```

Setup function logic:

```
<script setup>
import { client } from "./foobar"
 const userPhoto = ref();

 async function getPhoto(){
  const photo = await client.api("/me/photo/$value").get()
  console.log(photo.value)
  userPhoto.value = photo
 };
</script>
```

Returned result:
`{Blob, image:{id: default, size:48x48}}`

So how do I decode or download the Blob properly to display an image in my Vue markup?? I’ve tried `createObjectURL` and `FileReader()` without any luck. I’m sure there is a simple solution but I am not finding it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: what is the userphoto.value return? do you try convert to base64 and display it?

Comment: How did you try to use createObjectURL?

Comment: @Meow userPhoto.value returned the object listed in my post. Would this just be calling `btoa()` on the object?

Comment: @user2250152 I tried calling it on the whole object. Also tried it with `data:image/jpeg;base64,${userPhoto.value}`

Comment: for me what i do is  at the backend side there I convert example.png to base64 format after that i call the api which return me base64 code and i **this.gImage ='data:image/jpeg;base64,'+res.data.data;** insert this to the img tag.

Answer (score 0):

Explanation:

1. In below snippet as you can see I am passing the `objectId` of the Employee fetched from Graph previously.
2. Then making call for employee to get their Avatar/DP
3. The Graph Profile Photo endpoint returns binary Data of the photo.
4. Convert that binary data into `data:image/png;base64,<readAsDataURL>` URL e.g. `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSU...`
5. Use in `<img src="dataUrl"/>`

   ```
     let imageUrl = (await request.get(GRAPH_CONFIG.GRAPH_DP_ENDPT + objectId + "/photos/48x48/\$value", { responseType: 'arraybuffer', validateStatus: (status) => status === 200 || status === 404 }))
        if (imageUrl.status === 200) {
            let reader = new FileReader()
            let blob = new Blob([imageUrl.data], {type: 'image/jpeg'})
            reader.onload = (event) => {
                return event.target?.result.toString();
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(blob)
        }
   ```

Comment: Please don't post images (or links to images) of code. Anything text-based (code) should be posted directly into the answer and [formatted properly](https://$SITEURL$/help/formatting). By posting images we are not able to copy your code to use it. Also, it is not searchable so others can find your answer easily. For more, see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/6045800)